# UITapGestureRecognizer not working with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *PressRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
        [PressRecognizer1 setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
         [firstBtn addGestureRecognizer:PressRecognizer1];

-(void)handlePress:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)PressRecognizer {

    NSLog(@"working");
      if (PressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
          UIButton *whichButton=(UIButton *)[PressRecognizer view];
          NSLog(@"whichButton %d\n",whichButton.tag);
          if (whichButton.tag == 0) {
              NSLog(@"currentImageId1 %d",currentImageId1);
              [delegate imageZoom:currentImageId1];
          }
```

I have created a `UITabelView` with customcell which has three images per row.When tap on a image `hadlePress` method called.But i does not come inside first if condition.

Comment: @rckoenes where did u edit my code?

Comment: "UITapgesture not working with images" - Where is the image in your code ?

Comment: i added image on button.

Comment: maybe you can set a breakpoint to see what is the state of your gesture recognizer

Comment: I set break point after Log-working.It gives me exc_bad_access error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from apple docs:

Although taps are discrete gestures, they are discrete for each state of the gesture recognizer; thus the associated action message is sent when the gesture begins and is sent for each intermediate state until (and including) the ending state of the gesture. Code that handles tap gestures should therefore test for the state of the gesture, for example:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)     
     {         
          // handling code     
     } 
}
```

if you NSLog(@"%d",sender.state) inside the method (before the if statement) you'll see that the method is getting fired only with the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded state, thus you should change your

```
if (PressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
```

to

```
if (PressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
```